# JMSSerializer, serialize Entity values to (key, value) pair in json object

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

An Entity is given with these properties:

```
class Translation
{
  /**
   * @var string
   * @SerializedName("language_code")
   */
  private $lang;

  /**
   * @var string
   * @SerializedName("text")
   */
  private $translation;

  /**
   * @var int
   */
  private $language_id;
}
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
class DefaultController extends {
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $translation = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Translation')->findAll();
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $translationJson = $serializer->serialize($translation, 'json');

        return new Response($translationJson);
   }    
}
```

My front-end expects a json format like this:

```
 {
  "en" : "yes",
  "de" : "ja",
  "it" : "si"  
 }
```

My project is much more complex but this is a minified description of the problem. My only concern is how can I format the properties into a key-value pair in a json object.

Can I achieve that using Annotations?
If not, then how?

**EDIT**

Translation Entity has a ManyToOne relation with Languages Entity:

```
class Languages
{
  /**
   * @var int
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @var int
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Translation", mappedBy="translation_id", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
   */
  private $translations;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, I thought I didn't need to mention that this Entity has a ManyToOne relation with another. But @Matteo pointed to the right direction. With a small configuration of his code I managed to get this working.

Working with an object `$obj = new \StdClass;`  in the following `getWhateva()` didn't work at all. I didn't tried it in the controller though. The config is as follows:

Add in Languages.php:

```
/**
 * @VirtualProperty
 * @SerializedName("whateva")
 */
public function getWhateva() {
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($this-> translation as $elem) {
        $arr[$elem-> getLang()] = $elem->getTranslation();
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

and in Controller:

```
    $langu = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Language')->findAll();
    $languageJson = $serializer->serialize($language, 'json');
```

Output:

```
"whateva": {
       "en" : "yes",
       "de" : "ja",
       "it" : "si"  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements is not so standard to be implemented in a standard library: you want a collection of object will be translated into a single object and listed as an attribute with the value (as Json transposition data).

You can archive your objective with a custom implementation as follow:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $translation = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Translation')->findAll();

        $obj = new \StdClass;

        foreach ($translation as $elem)
        {
            // transform each value in an attribute/value of the single object 
            $obj->{$elem->getLang()} = $elem->getTranslation();
        }

        return new JsonResponse($obj);
   }
```

Hope this help